# suggestion regarding the maintainability of undo-redo states in image editing

Tags: java, image, undo-redo

I am developing an image editing app in java, which of-course will need undo-redo functionality. 
What have i done.... 
Have created a State class which will contain a bufferedimage, ref to prev state, ref to next state. Then formed a linked list of states, traversing back and forth with clicks of undo and redo buttons. 
So what do i want.... 
I have observed that bufferedimage occupies way too much memory...say 4 MB for just a medium (desktop) size image. Can you people suggest a better approach???

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) instead of the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) if your state uses too much memory.

You will have a linked list of UndoRedo objects, each containing just enough information to be able to run either the command of an undo, or the command of a redo.

You have to different ways to organize the commands:

- Have bi-directional commands. For example, when changing the color of a pixel, the operation must contain both the original color and the new one, so that the command can be run in both directions.
- Have two different commands for each undoredo bloc. For some commands which change everything on the image (like changing the scale or the brightness, where some information about the original image is lost), you have to store both the command to redo and the command to undo. It it's the full image, the memory footprint will be similar to what you already have.

Comment: Can you elaborate more with image editing example? I think what he is asking is how he can convert the Linked List of `BufferedImage` to some other data structure, so that it occupies lesser memory. I am trying to understand what you are trying to explain, so please can you do that? thx.

Comment: Paarth: Thanks for the comment. I am now using examples related to bitmap editors.

Comment: To reduce memory, can we utilize `getData(Rectangle r)`, `getRaster()` and `Raster` with `setRaster`? I think this can allow to change only the changed data inside a `BufferedImage`? Anyone has idea about this? thx.